# Oracle OCI statement vs ODBC statement discrepancy. (php)

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, odbc, oracle-call-interface

When connecting to a database with PHP I have been using an ODBC connection with the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM TAB.LE WHERE TAB.LE.Id = 1";
```

Where the tablename is `TAB.LE`. 
The code used to make the query isn't required here - but it works fine returning the correct result(s). When I use an OCI connection the same query fails:

```
$conn = oci_connect("username", "password", "database");

if($conn){

$query = "SELECT * FROM TAB.LE WHERE TAB.LE.Id = 1";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$res = oci_execute($query);

if($res){
     echo "success";
    }
else{
     echo "failed";
    }
}
```

I constantly see `failed` on the screen. I am stumped as to why. The odd thing is: the tablename `TAB.LE` works for the ODBC connection; however, when viewed in MS Access it shows as `TAB_LE`. I have attempted to use this different notation in the OCI connection but to no avail.

Comment: Well spotted; however, that was a typo when typing it into SO! I've edited it now. Thanks.

Comment: Also change `oci_execute($query);` to `oci_execute($stid);`

Comment: I've done that - still fails. **Edit:** Actually, it works a treat - I'd left in the wrong tablename, i.e, with an `_` instead of `.`. Thanks. Create an answer if you wish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[oci_execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) Executes a statement previously returned from `oci_parse().`

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
```

So change

```
$res = oci_execute($query);
```

To

```
  $res = oci_execute($stid);
```